# How can I run a task after other (already started) tasks are finished

Tags: python, task, celery, message-queue

I'm new to Celery and I'm trying to understand if it can solve my problem.

I need to start a number of tasks (`An`) and then run another task (`B`) after these are done. The problem is that tasks `An` are added sequentially and I don't want to wait for the last one to be added before I start the first one. Can I configure task `B` to execute after tasks `An` are done?

Now to the real scenario:

- Task `An` - Process a file uploaded by user (Added after each file is
  uploaded)
- Task `B`  - do something with the results of processing all
  uploaded files

Alternative solutions are welcome as well

Answer (score 1):

For sure you can do this, celery canvas supports many options, inluding the behaviour you require, running a task after a group of tasks ... it is called **"Chords"**, e.g.:

```
from celery import chord
from tasks import task_upload1, task_upload2, task_upload3, final_execution

result = chord(task_upload1.s(), task_upload2.s(), task_upload3.s())(final_execution.s())
get_required_result = result.get()
```

you can refer to [this](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) link for more details

Comment: This won't work. `An` is a task that processes a file, not uploads it. All `An` tasks are identical except the data they are called with. This data isn't ready right away. So I know there will be 100 tasks to wait for but I don't have the data to start all of them (or define a chord) right away. And I don't want to wait for all data to be ready before I start. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: According to your latter definition to what you want, the chord still should work, the task_upload thing is my naming to the task, you can change the name or behaviour of the task as much as you want, you should define your tasks somwhere in the code (conventionally, in the tasks.py, but it can be anywhere) .. Regarding that you don't have the parameters of tasks .. I'm not sure what you mean!

Comment: But according to my partial understanding of what you want, you can make the task check the DB for data availability, and if not there, the task can be retried after some period of time, and that before moving to the next task in the chord (even chains) .. otherwise, please let me know if I can help.

Comment: I can't poll for the data because the task itself is the first place where the data is stored in the DB. Initially the data comes from the client (browser), file by file via callback. But I know in advance that I want to finalize all tasks once they are ready and I know in advance how many files I'll eventually get.

Answer (score 0):

With RabbitMQ you can get exact behavior using [message acknowledgment](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) and [aggregator pattern](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Aggregator.html).

You start worker, that consumes messages (`A`) and do some work(*process a file uploaded by user* in your case), but doesn't sent `ack` when finished. Instead it takes next message form queue and if it's `A` task again, he is doing the same thing. At some point he will receive task `B` and could process all previous `A`'s results, all atones and send `ack` to all of them.

Unfortunately, this scenario can't be done with Celery, because you have to specify **all** `A` tasks and final `B` task(*chains, chords, callbacks, etc.*) on creating time.

Alternatively, you can save `Task.id` for each successful `A` task in separate queue (*not Celery queue*) and process this messages, when executing `B` task. Celery can fit for this algorithm.